# Campo data entrando 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: php, joomla

O campo data de minha aplicação está entrando com o valores `0000-00-00 00:00:00`, porém não estou conseguindo achar o arquivo que faz o insert,

A função que faz gravar no banco é esta:

```
$db = & JFactory::getDBO();
if ($db->connected()) {
   $data =new stdClass();
   $data->nome = $_POST['nome'];
   $data->email = $_POST['email'];
   $data->telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
   $data->cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
   $data->estado = $_POST['estado']; 
   $db->insertObject('database_orcamentos', $data);
```

Comment: Veja no banco de dados se coluna de data tem um valor default.

Comment: Está OK, com datetime valor nulo NÃO!

Comment: Então o problema parece ser que a data está sendo convertida errada. Em `insertObject()` não tem nenhuma pista?

Comment: Então, só tem essa linha mesmo $db->insertObject('database_orcamentos', $data); 

Eu peguei essa buxa no trampo, e minha praia não é joomla ... e sim wordpress.

Comment: Qual o nome da coluna de data?

Comment: a coluna se chama created

Comment: depois de atribuir o estado, adicione essa linha `$data->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');`

Comment: Show amigo, obrigado!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode força um valor para esse campo data, ao criar uma propriedade com o mesmo nome da coluna.

```
$data->estado = $_POST['estado'];
$data->created = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```